# Cannot convert value of type 'GenericClass<Class>' to expected argument type 'GenericClass<Class>?'

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

Hi I want to make sure a function only accepts specific classes as a generic in a class.

So I did this:

```
func request<T: JSONObject>(liveData: LiveData<T>?, arrayLiveData: LiveData<[T]>?, 
    callback:  (([String: Any]) -> ())?,) {
    ...
}
```

So here I only want to allow `T` to be a subclass of `JSONObject`.

Sometimes it works sometimes not.

JSONObject.swift:

```
class JSONObject: NSObject, NSCoding {
    internal var json: [String: Any]

    required init?(_ json: [String: Any]) {
        self.json = json
        super.init()
    }
    override init() {
        fatalError("Not implemented")
    }

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.json)
    }
    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Must be overwritten")
    }
    class func decodeJSON(_ decoder: NSCoder) -> [String: Any] {
        return decoder.decodeObject() as! [String: Any]
    }
}
```

a subclass:
Content.swift

```
class Content: JSONObject {
    // MARK: Properties

    // MARK: Initialization
    required init?(_ json: [String : Any]) {
        super.init(json)
    }

   required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(JSONObject.decodeJSON(decoder))
    }
}
```

and this subclass of `JSONObject` get's subclassed as wel, so I can use it in the fucction.

```
class Playlist: Content {
    required init?(_ json: [String : Any]) {
        super.init(json)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(JSONObject.decodeJSON(decoder))
    }

}
```

I call the function like this:

`request(liveData: LiveData<Playlist>(), arraryLiveData: nil, callback: nil)`

I have to use subclassing so I know for sure that every `T` in the function `request` has the initialiser `T(_ json: [String: Any])`

*BUT:* When I try to compile XCode complains at the `request` call

`Cannot convert value of type 'LiveData<Playlist>' to expected argument type 'LiveData<JSONObject>?'`

LiveData.swift

```
class LiveData<T> {

   private var senderId: String
   private var value: T?
   private var observers: [LiveDataObserver]

   init(senderId: String) {
       self.senderId = senderId
       self.observers = []
   }

   func getValue() -> T? {
       return value
   }

   func setValue(_ value: T) {
       self.value = value
       notifyObservers()
   }

   func sendError(_ error: LiveDataError) {
       for observer in observers {
          observer.errorOccurred(senderId, error)
       }
   }

   func sendError(_ string: String) {
       sendError(liveDataError(from: string))
   }

   private func notifyObservers() {
       for observer in observers {
           observer.valueChanged(senderId, value)
       }
   }

   func observe(observer: LiveDataObserver) {
       observers.append(observer)
       // Send initial value if value is present
       if value != nil {
           observer.valueChanged(senderId, value)
       }
   }

   func hasObservers() -> Bool {
       return observers.count > 0
   }

   func removeObservers() {
       observers.removeAll()
   }
}
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong and when?

Comment: @JeremyP I get this Error Cannot convert value of type 'LiveData<Playlist>' to expected argument type 'LiveData<JSONObject>?'

when I try to call `request( ... )`

Comment: And what is the declaration of `LiveData`

Comment: Added the declaration

Comment: I don't know the answer, but my guess is that the compiler is inferring `T` in `request` to be of type `JSONObject` instead of `PlayList`. That might be because you have passed `nil` as the second parameter. To test the theory, create a let as follows `let dummy: LiveData<[PlayList]>? = nil` and assign that to the second parameter.

Comment: Still failing with the same error

Answer (score 0):

YEEEAY,
Guess what helped.

Reordering the parameters of the `request` functions.

The compiler seems to have its problems when the generic type is the first parameter.

Just change

`request<T: JSONObject>(liveData: LiveData<T>?, arrayLiveData: LiveData<[T]>?, 
    callback:  (([String: Any]) -> ())?)`

to

`request<T: JSONObject>(callback:  (([String: Any]) -> ())?, liveData: LiveData<T>?, arrayLiveData: LiveData<[T]>?)`

and everything works fine